# How to delegate Container1.Resolve<T> to Container2.Resolve<T>, if Container1 cannot resolve T?

Tags: dependency-injection, spring4d

Using Spring4D, I would like to build a container that delegates service resolution to another container, if it cannot resolve a service -- something along these lines:

```
function TContainer.Resolve<T>: T;
begin
  if not TryResolve<T>(Result) then
    Result := OtherContainer.Resolve<T>;
end;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so called subdependency resolvers (future versions will just call them type resolver) inside a container that handle specific types or type patterns (like being able to resolve `TArray<T>` or `IList<T>` where T is something being registered).

You can implement your own that checks if a type is not inside of the container you attached this resolver to and then delegate the resolve chain for this type to another container.

Here is some example code how to achieve that (without freeing objects)

```
uses
  Spring,
  Spring.Container,
  Spring.Container.Core,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TFoo = class

  end;

  TBar = class
  private
    fFoo: TFoo;
  public
    constructor Create(const foo: TFoo);
    property Foo: TFoo read fFoo;
  end;

  TSubContainerResolver = class(TInterfacedObject, ISubDependencyResolver)
  private
    fContainer: TContainer;
    fSubContainer: TContainer;
  public
    constructor Create(const container, subContainer: TContainer);

    function CanResolve(const context: ICreationContext;
      const dependency: TDependencyModel; const argument: TValue): Boolean;
    function Resolve(const context: ICreationContext;
      const dependency: TDependencyModel; const argument: TValue): TValue;
  end;

{ TBar }

constructor TBar.Create(const foo: TFoo);
begin
  fFoo := foo;
end;

{ TSubContainerResolver }

constructor TSubContainerResolver.Create(const container, subContainer: TContainer);
begin
  fContainer := container;
  fSubContainer := subContainer;
end;

function TSubContainerResolver.CanResolve(const context: ICreationContext;
  const dependency: TDependencyModel; const argument: TValue): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not fContainer.Kernel.Registry.HasService(dependency.TypeInfo)
    and fSubContainer.Kernel.Resolver.CanResolve(context, dependency, argument);
end;

function TSubContainerResolver.Resolve(const context: ICreationContext;
  const dependency: TDependencyModel; const argument: TValue): TValue;
begin
  Result := fSubContainer.Kernel.Resolver.Resolve(context, dependency, argument);
end;

procedure ScenarioOne;
var
  c1, c2: TContainer;
  b: TBar;
begin
  c1 := TContainer.Create;
  c2 := TContainer.Create;
  c1.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(TSubContainerResolver.Create(c1, c2));

  // dependency in subcontainer
  c1.RegisterType<TBar>;
  c1.Build;
  c2.RegisterType<TFoo>;
  c2.Build;

  b := c1.Resolve<TBar>;
  Assert(Assigned(b.fFoo));
end;

procedure ScenarioTwo; 
var
  c1, c2: TContainer;
  b: TBar;
begin
  c1 := TContainer.Create;
  c2 := TContainer.Create;

  c1.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(TSubContainerResolver.Create(c1, c2));
  c2.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(TSubContainerResolver.Create(c2, c1));

  // type in subcontainer but dependency in parent container
  c1.RegisterType<TFoo>;
  c1.Build;
  c2.RegisterType<TBar>;
  c2.Build;

  b := c1.Resolve<TBar>;
  Assert(Assigned(b.fFoo));
end;

begin
  ScenarioOne;
  ScenarioTwo;
end.
```